# A model has 7 independent variables. What is the dimensionality of the model?

Tags: regression

A model has 7 independent variables.  What is the dimensionality of the model?

Comment: Barring no duplicate variables, 7.

Comment: what is the definition of "the dimensionality of the model"?

Comment: The answer could literally be any positive integer, infinite, or not applicable: please provide more information about the model.